# Triple USB bridge - Does it exist

Tags: usb

### Triple USB Bridge

**What are USB to USB bridge?**

It allows the user to connect two USB hosts for data transfer.
After plugging it between the two machines, the drivers will be loaded automatically, and the user will get a new network interface on each machine  [Like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005OTPVMY)

**Question:**

Are there versions for more than two hosts?

Comment: I've never seen one, probably because the only real use case for that is data transfer without having to setup a network. If you have 2+ machines you're probably better off setting up an actual network with ethernet + switch.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any products currently available (Sept 2014) that act as an IP over USB router for more than 2 devices.

The closest approximation would be to get a usb/ethernet dongle for 3 computers and plug them all into a hub or router.